# Site Contact Form Does Not Work

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out why my contact form on my web site wont work...

When I fill in my forms required info and send, all I get is a blank page with 'http://www.pinkpigdesign.co.uk/php/mail_form.php' in the URL. Forwarding email address is working perfectly.

Both codes are direct from templates.

My html code:

```
    <form class="required-form" action="php/mail_form.php"  method="POST">
    <ol class="forms">

    <li><label for="first_name"><em class="required">*</em> First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="required"></li>

    <li><label for="last_name"><em class="required">*</em> Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="required"></li>

    <li><label for="telephone">Telephone</label>
    <input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone"></li>

    <li><label for="email"><em class="required">*</em> Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="required"></li>

    <li><label for="message"><em class="required">*</em> Message</label>
    <textarea name="message" id="message" class="required" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea></li>

<li class="buttons submit"><button type="submit">Submit</button></li>

</ol>
```

My php code:

```
$yourEmail = "enquiries@pinkpigdesign.co.uk"; 
$yourWebsite = "www.pinkpigdesin.co.uk"; 
$thanksPage = 'thankyou.html'; 
$maxPoints = 4; 
$error_msg = null;
$result = null;

function isBot() {
$bots = array("Indy", "Blaiz", "Java", "libwww-perl", "Python", "OutfoxBot", "User-Agent", "PycURL", "AlphaServer", "T8Abot", "Syntryx", "WinHttp", "WebBandit", "nicebot");

$isBot = false;
foreach ($bots as $bot)
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $bot) !== false)
    $isBot = true;

if (empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) || $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] == " ")
    $isBot = true;

exit("Bots not allowed.</p>");
}

foreach ($badwords as $word)
    if (strpos($_POST['comments'], $word) !== false)
        $points += 2;

foreach ($exploits as $exploit)
    if (strpos($_POST['comments'], $exploit) !== false)
        $points += 2;

if (strpos($_POST['comments'], "http://") !== false || strpos($_POST['comments'], "www.") !== false)
    $points += 2;
if (isset($_POST['nojs']))
    $points += 1;
if (preg_match("/(<.*>)/i", $_POST['comments']))
    $points += 2;
if (strlen($_POST['name']) < 3)
    $points += 1;
if (strlen($_POST['comments']) < 15 || strlen($_POST['comments'] > 1500))
    $points += 2;

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
    $_POST[$key] = trim($value);

if (empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['comments'])) {
    $error_msg .= "Name, e-mail and comments are required fields. \n";
} elseif (strlen($_POST['name']) > 15) {
    $error_msg .= "The name field is limited at 15 characters. Your first name or nickname will do! \n";
} elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-'\s]*$/", stripslashes($_POST['name']))) {
    $error_msg .= "The name field must not contain special characters. \n";
} elseif (!preg_match('/^([a-z0-9])(([-a-z0-9._])*([a-z0-9]))*\@([a-z0-9])(([a-z0-9-])*([a-z0-9]))+' . '(\.([a-z0-9])([-a-z0-9_-])?([a-z0-9])+)+$/i', strtolower($_POST['email']))) {
    $error_msg .= "That is not a valid e-mail address. \n";
} elseif (!empty($_POST['url']) && !preg_match('/^(http|https):\/\/(([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)(\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+)(:(\d+))?\/?/i', $_POST['url']))
    $error_msg .= "Invalid website url.";

if ($error_msg == NULL && $points <= $maxPoints) {
    $subject = "Automatic Form Email";

    $message = "You received this e-mail message through your website: \n\n";
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
        $message .= ucwords($key) . ": " . clean($val) . "\r\n";
    }
    $message .= 'IP: '.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\r\n";
    $message .= 'Browser: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']."\r\n";
    $message .= 'Points: '.$points;

    if (strstr($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'], "Win")) {
        $headers   = "From: $yourEmail \r\n";
        $headers  .= "Reply-To: {$_POST['email']}";
    } else {
        $headers   = "From: $yourWebsite <$yourEmail> \r\n";
        $headers  .= "Reply-To: {$_POST['email']}";
    }

    if (mail($yourEmail,$subject,$message,$headers)) {
        if (!empty($thanksPage)) {
            header("Location: $thanksPage");
            exit;
        } else {
            $result = 'Your mail was successfully sent.';
        }
    } else {
        $error_msg = 'Your mail could not be sent this time.';
    }
} else {
    if (empty($error_msg))
        $error_msg = 'Your mail looks too much like spam, and could not be sent this time. ['.$points.']';
}
    }
function get_data($var) {
if (isset($_POST[$var]))
    echo htmlspecialchars($_POST[$var]);
}
```

I probably can't see the error for looking so I hope someone can shed some light on this problem... Cheers!

Comment: I think we should more trust our senses here. You feel lost, right? So well, trust your senses about feeling lost. With that large wall of code, heavily nested, this is no surprise. Instead put different parts into functions to make your code more simple and more easy to debug. http://php.net/functions

Comment: And what you want to see. From your php code there is nothing to show.

Comment: Start with a shorter code, read a tutorial. What you are using has loads of unnecessary code that doesn't belong.

Answer (score 0):

A blank page when expecting some output (anything at all) "usually" indicates a PHP error and so the script halts and no output is give.
You REALLY need to access your error logs and see what it returns when developing, or issue them out to the page while developing.

This is a simple one that my pushing this out on my dev area provided me the answer to your question in my PHP error log:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}' in sites/site1/test.php on line 89

```
} else {
    if (empty($error_msg))
        $error_msg = 'Your mail looks too much like spam, and could not be sent this time. ['.$points.']';
}
    } //This shouldn't be here..?
```

Remove that uneeded `}` and try again.

Also, why are you using a mixture of IFs with and without curly braces? `{ }`
You should stick to one and keep your code consistent throughout. It's personal choice with or without (among other arguments), and personally I use them, always.
With them decent editors (I use vim) use bracket highlighting and when you click on a brace or bracket, the editor will highlight the paired one (either open or closing).

Example, when I click on your code in my Vim, and click the curly bracket not needed, it does not highlight another one, so shows there is no pair and therefore on it's own.